# IDA declare a function that passes return value on FPU stack

Tags: ida

The usual way to return a value is by passing it in `EAX`. I know also that a 64 Bit value would be returned in `EAX:EDX`. However I have now a function that calcluates the localtime to miliseconds into a 64Bit double value, and the function returns it in the FPU stack, so the caller, upon return, pops it off from there.

IDA identified this function as `void` and when I try to declare it as `double` it says that it is a "bad declaraton". Even if IDA would accept it, this would mean that the value would have been passed back using `EAX:EDX` right?

According to Wikipedia calling conventions, float/doubles are returned using the x87 registers as a standard. So how do I tell IDA this, resp. why doesn't it accept double as the return value?

**Update**

I found another function which returns a double, and this one is correctly using the `double` as the return value, when I press `Y` to change the function. So whats wrong with this one?

`void __userpurge GetTimeInMilliseconds(unsigned __int16 nHour<ax>, unsigned __int16 nMinute<dx>, unsigned __int16 nSeconds<cx>, unsigned __int32 nMilliseconds)`

When I try to change the `void` to `double`, then it failes. I assume that I may have to specify the returnvalue manually, but how do I do this for a FPU register?

Something like this, also doesn't work, so probalby there is some different name for the FPU?

```
void __userpurge GetTimeInMilliseconds<st>(unsigned __int16 nHour<ax>, unsigned __int16 nMinute<dx>, unsigned __int16 nSeconds<cx>, unsigned __int32 nMilliseconds)
```

Comment: Already answered at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2968/1562

Comment: @JasonGeffner, Unfortunately this is not covered, because the answers only deal with regular registers and not with FPU registers. I haven't found a way yet, how to represent a returnvalue which is passed in the FPU and then retrieved by the caller with the `fstp` instruction. Apparently this is the way how i.e. gcc returns a double.

Comment: `st` is not a register, but `st0` through `st7` are, and these FPU registers *do* work with IDA's type declaration overrides.