# What compiler uses a calling convention that uses EAX as the first argument, then pushes onto the stack?

Tags: c++, calling-conventions

I recently asked to question: [How can an IA-32 program seemingly compiled with MSVC send its sole argument via EAX?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16911/how-can-an-ia-32-program-seemingly-compiled-with-msvc-send-its-sole-argument-via/16915#16915) After posting the question, I found that another function passed the first argument in `EAX` and then pushed its remaining argument. The caller then cleans up the stack.

The calling code:

```
.text:00402465                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_4]
    ...
.text:00402469                 push    eax
.text:0040246A                 mov     eax, [ebp+hWnd]
.text:0040246D                 call    openFileDialog
.text:00402472                 add     esp, 4
```

And the function itself:

```
.text:00411730 openFileDialog  proc near
.text:00411730
    ...
.text:00411730 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:00411730
.text:00411730                 push    ebp
.text:00411731                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00411733                 sub     esp, 18h
.text:00411736                 cmp     byte_42AE1D, FALSE
.text:0041173D                 push    ebx
.text:0041173E                 push    esi
.text:0041173F                 push    edi
.text:00411740                 mov     esi, eax
    ...
.text:00411789                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:0041178C                 push    eax
.text:0041178D                 push    esi
.text:0041178E                 call    openFileDialog_Compat
.text:00411793                 add     esp, 8
```

As you can see, in the function, the value of `EAX` is saved before anything can affect it, so it is definitely being used as a parameter. Later, the pushed argument is passed to a normal __cdecl function.

The program is linked to use msvcr100.dll and uses MSVC style throughout (Such as __security_cookie, MSVC name mangling, etc.), so it would appear to have been compiled with Visual C++, but this unusual calling convention makes me question that.

Comment: When using "Whole Program Optimization", the compiler may use whatever calling convention fits for functions with internal linkage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a program compiled with "Whole Program Optimization" or "Link-time code generation". [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh):

> When /LTCG is used to link modules compiled with /Og, /O1, /O2, or
>   /Ox, the following optimizations are performed:
>
> - Cross-module inlining
> - Interprocedural register allocation (64-bit operating systems only)
> - **Custom calling convention (x86 only)**
> - Small TLS displacement (x86 only)
> - Stack double alignment (x86 only)
> - Improved memory disambiguation (better interference information for global variables and input parameters)

Comment: Thank you. This is something I have not encountered before. I've only ever thought from the compiler point of view and the described standards.

Answer (score 0):

check [Calling Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions) that msvc support yet.
as for the function name openFileDialog, it's a c# func? combining C# and C++
via CLR?? strange things may happen. MS dose not need to expose these details
to public.